# MySQL SELECT WHERE PERSON_NAME = Function not working

Tags: mysql, sql

So I'm trying out SQL and teaching myself in small steps and for some reason this isn't working. All I get is the table content names, a grid will pop up showing "PERSON_NAME PERSON_SURNAME BIRTH_PLACE BIRTH_DATE YEARLY_WAGE PERSON_AGE in a grid box in MySQL but not the values I've inserted in them. Here's the code

```
CREATE TABLE PEOPLES (
PERSON_NAME VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
PERSON_SURNAME VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
BIRTH_PLACE VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
BIRTH_DATE date NOT NULL,
YEARLY_WAGE INT (50) NOT NULL,
PERSON_AGE INT (50) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO PEOPLES (PERSON_NAME, PERSON_SURNAME, BIRTH_PLACE, BIRTH_DATE, YEARLY_WAGE, PERSON_AGE)
VALUES ("Trollfire", "Lolmay", "Montenegro", 29042000, 600000, 19);
INSERT INTO PEOPLES (PERSON_NAME, PERSON_SURNAME, BIRTH_PLACE, BIRTH_DATE, YEARLY_WAGE, PERSON_AGE)
VALUES ("Thomas", "Trainson", "Albania", 17091964, 100000, 60);
INSERT INTO PEOPLES (PERSON_NAME, PERSON_SURNAME, BIRTH_PLACE, BIRTH_DATE, YEARLY_WAGE, PERSON_AGE)
VALUES ("Stefan", "Savic", "Serbia", 19021972, 234567, 25);
INSERT INTO PEOPLES (PERSON_NAME, PERSON_SURNAME, BIRTH_PLACE, BIRTH_DATE, YEARLY_WAGE, PERSON_AGE)
VALUES ("Milo", "Djukanovic", "Croatia", 999999, 01011922, 70);
INSERT INTO PEOPLES (PERSON_NAME, PERSON_SURNAME, BIRTH_PLACE, BIRTH_DATE, YEARLY_WAGE, PERSON_AGE)
VALUES ("Vladimir", "Putin", "Russia", 444444, 11121933, 62);
INSERT INTO PEOPLES (PERSON_NAME, PERSON_SURNAME, BIRTH_PLACE, BIRTH_DATE, YEARLY_WAGE, PERSON_AGE)
VALUES ("Cristiano", "Ronaldo", "France", 777777, 03031993, 34);
INSERT INTO PEOPLES (PERSON_NAME, PERSON_SURNAME, BIRTH_PLACE, BIRTH_DATE, YEARLY_WAGE, PERSON_AGE)
VALUES ("Lionel", "Messi", "Spain", 101010, 10101910, 40);
SELECT * FROM PEOPLES
WHERE PERSON_NAME = "Vladimir";
```

Comment: try using `person_name = 'Vladimir';`. Use single quotes

Comment: Same for insert statements

Comment: It should work without any issues

Comment: It works now! Thank you for the help everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your date literals are incorrect, possibly among other problems in your insert statement.  Here is a version with syntax which works:

```
INSERT INTO PEOPLES (PERSON_NAME, PERSON_SURNAME, BIRTH_PLACE, BIRTH_DATE,
    YEARLY_WAGE, PERSON_AGE)
VALUES
    ('Trollfire', 'Lolmay', 'Montenegro', '2000-04-29', 600000, 19);
```

### Demo

Note that string literals typically should use single, not double, quotes.  Also, [see the MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-literals.html) for valid date literal formats.

Comment: This solved the problem. Thank you for your help, it seems the issue was I didn't even put the data types in the right order when inserting them and had multiple tables going on.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your table only has one row in it.

```
mysql> select * from peoples;
+-------------+----------------+-------------+------------+-------------+------------+
| PERSON_NAME | PERSON_SURNAME | BIRTH_PLACE | BIRTH_DATE | YEARLY_WAGE | PERSON_AGE |
+-------------+----------------+-------------+------------+-------------+------------+
| Lionel      | Messi          | Spain       | 2010-10-10 |    10101910 |         40 |
+-------------+----------------+-------------+------------+-------------+------------+
```

This is because most of your inserts failed.

```
ERROR 1292 (22007): Incorrect date value: '29042000' for column 'BIRTH_DATE' at row 1
```

I assume that's `DDMMYYYY`. Dates are typically `YYYYMMDD` and not numbers. One insert happened to have a valid date.